# How to add an object to an existing object, something like doing push in an array, but in reducer for redux

Tags: reactjs, object, redux

**Goals:** Be able to add, replace, remove items from an object.

What current object looks like:

`{123: {...}, 1234: [...}, 12345: {...}}`

I have a reducer in which I am trying to add a new item or replace and existing one to an array like object.

So I have:

`return { ...state, all: state.all[data.id] = data }`

but all this is doing is erasing the entire `all` object and setting it to the one object. I would much like to have something like mirroring the functionality of `.push`.

I also need to do this for an updated item, so replacing an item in the Object list.

Lastly I think I know how to do the delete, but just to make sure this is right.

```
delete state.all[data.id];
return state
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, do not mutate state:

```
const newState = {...state};
```

Then update the all value inside new state to whatever you want it to be

```
const { all } = newState;
all[data.id] = data;
```

Lastly, return the new updated state

```
return {...state, ...{ all }};
```

Comment: Wouldnt it be just `return {...state, ...all }`

Comment: @TaylorAustin that would spread the content of the "all" value instead of adding all: {} to the object.

Comment: Okay and for update you would do the same exact thing correct? because that would override the current object with that key in the list ? And did I do the delete the correct way?

Comment: Actually now that I think of it I probably need to make a copy so it would be something like `delete newState.all[data.id]` after that just `return newState`?

Comment: If you want to delete the value then yes, that is correct.